# Как анимировать объект в Python?

Tags: python, анимация, pyqt, opencv, qpainter

У меня есть код на *Pygame*, который вращает нужное мне изображение вокруг своей оси:

```
while True:
   pygame.event.pump()
   event_handler()
      if i == 0:
         prize, needed_angle, angle, deg_count, a = randomize()
         print(prize)
         i += 1
      if angle >= needed_angle:
         DSP.fill(backgr)
         pygame.display.update()
         i = event_handler()
         pass
      elif angle < needed_angle:
         DSP.fill(backgr)
         deg_count += a
         angle += a
         image_new = pygame.transform.rotozoom(image, angle, 1)
         image1_new = image_new.get_rect()
         image1_new.center = (400,400)
         if (needed_angle - deg_count) <= 495:
         if (a - 0.0361) > 0:
             a -= 0.0361
         else:
             pass
      else:
         pass

         DSP.blit(image1, (100,100))
         DSP.blit(image_new, image1_new)
         pygame.display.update()
```

Выглядит это примерно вот так:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQxdYb_iKU4

Однако если окно теряет фокус, то код перестает работать. 
Как я понял, это никак не пофиксить (мне нужно чтобы всё работало и без фокуса).

Поэтому я ищу аналоги, но никак не могу найти подходящий.

Пожалуйста, скажите есть ли такая возможность в **`PyQt`** или **`OpenCV`**, или я совсем не там ищу?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Насколько я знаю сам PyGame для обновления окна не требует фокуса. Я так понимаю, просто ваше приложение написано так, чтобы оно работало только при фокусе.

Comment: в PyQt есть qml. он позволяет делать что угодно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyQt5, пробуйте:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QPixmap, QPainter, QImage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QApplication, QVBoxLayout


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.imageLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.imageLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.imageLabel)

        # Исходное изображение
        self.srcImage = QImage('fg.png')    
        self.imageLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.srcImage).scaled(250, 250))

        self.timer = QTimer(interval=500)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.doAnticlockwise)
        self.timer.start()

    def doAnticlockwise(self):
        # против часовой стрелки 45 градусов
        image = QImage(self.srcImage.size(),
                       QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(image)
        # Возьмите центр изображения как источник
        hw = self.srcImage.width()  / 2
        hh = self.srcImage.height() / 2
        painter.translate(hw, hh)
        painter.rotate(-45)                         # Вращение -45 градусов
        painter.drawImage(-hw, -hh, self.srcImage)  # Оформи картину
        painter.end()
        self.srcImage = image                       # Заменить 
        self.imageLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.srcImage).scaled(250, 250))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]